# Fallback destination for deep links in Compose Navigation

Tags: android, android-deep-link, jetpack-compose-navigation

Suppose that my app handles all `example.com` deep links, but the `NavHost` within `MainActivity` handles only `example.com`, `example.com/account`, and `example.com/account/detail`, while other paths are forwarded to another activity called `WebViewActivity`. How to create a fallback destination that will forward to another activity?

```kotlin
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "root") {
  composable(
    "root",
    deepLinks = listOf(
      navDeepLink { uriPattern = "example.com" }
    ),
  ) {
  }
  composable(
    "account",
    deepLinks = listOf(
      navDeepLink { uriPattern = "example.com/account" }
    ),
  ) {
  }
  composable(
    "accountdetail",
    deepLinks = listOf(
      navDeepLink { uriPattern = "example.com/account/detail" }
    ),
  ) {
  }
  other("fallback") { // How?
  }
}
```

What I've tried so far:

1. Using `example.com/.*` pattern: it takes precedence over `accountdetail` destination.

   ```kotlin
   composable(
     "fallback",
     deepLinks = listOf(
       navDeepLink { uriPattern = "example.com/.*" }
     ),
   ) {
     val url = it.arguments?.getParcelable<Intent>(NavController.KEY_DEEP_LINK_INTENT)
       ?.dataString
   }
   ```
2. Catching in `home` destination and taking the URL from `Activity.intent`: too hacky.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the end, instead of creating a fallback route, I do a simple hack.

```kotlin
NavHost(...) { ... }

LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    // startingDeepLink is from Activity.intent?.data
    if (startingDeepLink?.let { navController.graph.hasDeepLink(it) } == false) {
        val shouldFinish = navController.popBackStack()
        if (shouldFinish) {
            // Finish the activity.
        }
        // Handle startingDeepLink here.
        // ...
    }
}
```